# Which microservice ends transaction in Choreography Based Saga Pattern?

Tags: microservices, distributed-transactions, saga

Each microservice sends an event to next microservice to run their local transactions in choreography based saga pattern. So, which microservice ends transaction? Last microservice which has no next ends and aprove transaction or last microservice sends OK to first starting microservice to commit overall process?

Answer (score 0):

The choreography means that services knows about their counterparts and decides from what is outcome of other services. No communication with some "central coordinator".

If we say the A communicates to B which communicates to C (A -> B -> C) then A does some action asks for outcome of B, B does some action and asks for outcome of C and C does some action. The outcomes go in opposite way (A <- B <- C).

Let's expect that all service actions were successful. Thus C persists data and responds to B that the task was successful done and outcome is OK. B knows there is no other services that it waits for and the saga step can be validated as successful at B. Then it responds to A of success and A knows there is no other service to wait for and may ends its saga step with success as well.
The example of two services communicating over queue can be found at https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html